# jQuery not reading JSON instances

Tags: jquery, json, calendar

A jQuery script which reads a JSON file, and places the data into a DIV is showing the Date, but not the Location, Description or Link.

An example of a JSON set is here:

```
{
"id": "6dq1oht32tdp66i9s2bd9a21lk@group.calendar.google.com",
"title": null,
"events": [{
      "start": {
        "date": null,
        "time": "2016-02-16T10:00:00+01:00"
      },
      "end": {
        "date": null,
        "time": "2016-02-16T11:00:00+01:00"
      },
      "location": "Kreuzberg, Berlin, Germany",
      "description": "Basketball Test",
      "color_id": "1",
      "ical_uid": "a5fq8vu8gur943bucj5ajr2mb4@google.com"
    }
```

There is a jQuery script here:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

(function(window, $) {

    var CALENDAR_ENDPOINT ='http://antibang.com/js/berlinbraves/calendar/?tk=9832187dsamj__dsaj7321njdsa';

    var _leftCalendar, _rightCalendar;

    function _parseEvents(eEventData) {

        var converted, formatted;

        converted = [];

        eEventData.forEach(function(eItem) {

            formatted = moment(eItem.start.time);

            converted.push({

                date: formatted.format('YYYY-MM-DD'),

                formatted_date: formatted.format('DD.MM.YY'),
                formatted_time: formatted.format('HH:mm') + ' Uhr',

                location: eItem.location,
                description: eItem.description,
                link: eItem.ical_uid,
                category: eItem.color_id == null ? 'default' : eItem.color_id

            });

        });

        return converted;

    }


    function _prepareDays() {

        // hover over day cell

        $('.clndr-event').hover(function() {

            var $this;

            $this = $(this);

            $('#event-detail').show();

            $('#event-detail').removeClass();
            $('#event-detail').addClass('category-' + $this.data('category'));

            $('#event-detail-date').text($this.data('date'));
            $('#event-detail-loca').text($this.data('location'));

            $('#event-detail').css('top', Math.round($this.offset().top) );
            $('#event-detail').css('left', Math.round($this.offset().left) );



        }, function() {

            $('#event-detail').hide();

        });

    }
```

I cannot see why Date would render, but Location, Description and ical_uid wouldn't?

The calendar system being used is CLNDR, and the data is being set in this script here:

```
    <script type="text/template" id="template-calendar">

<div class="clndr-single">

    <div class="clndr-month"><%= month %> </div>
       <div class="clndr-year"><%= year %> </div>

    <div class="clndr-grid">

        <div class="days-of-the-week">

            <% _.each(daysOfTheWeek, function(day) { %>
                <div class="header-day"><%= day %></div>
            <% }); %>

            <div class="days">

                <% _.each(days, function(day) { %>

                    <div class="<%= day.classes %>">

                        <div class="clndr-day"><%= day.day %></div>

                        <div class="clndr-events">

                            <% _.each(day.events, function(event) { %>
                                <div class="clndr-event category-<%= event.category %>"
                                    data-description="<%= event.description %>"
                                    data-category="<%= event.category %>"
                                    data-time="<%= event.time %>"
                                    data-date="<%= event.date %>"
                                ></div>
                            <% }); %>

                        </div>


                    </div>

                <% }); %>

            </div>

        </div>

   </div>

</div>
```

Comment: How is the element data being set? What calendar system is this?

Comment: The element data is being set through a PHP script.

The full JSON data tree can be seen here: 
[link](http://antibang.com/js/berlinbraves/calendar/?tk=9832187dsamj__dsaj7321njdsa)]

The calender system is CLNDR, and it's being set through another script above it which I have added into the main post.

Comment: so are the data attributes in template being properly set when you inspect the live html in browser dev tools? Also try logging `$this.data()` to console and see what full object contains

Comment: No, the attributes aren't being properly set in the live HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The HTML data attributes wern't being set correctly, and therefore there was seemingly no template in which to place the information. Working as soon as the template (at the top) was modified.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
    var obj =[{"id":"6dq1oht32tdp66i9s2bd9a21lk@group.calendar.google.com","title":null,"events":[{"start":{"date":null,"time":"2016-02-16T10:00:00+01:00"},"end":{"date":null,"time":"2016-02-16T11:00:00+01:00"},"location":"Kreuzberg, Berlin, Germany","description":"Basketball Test","color_id":"1","ical_uid":"a5fq8vu8gur943bucj5ajr2mb4@google.com"},{"start":{"date":null,"time":"2016-02-15T20:00:00+01:00"},"end":{"date":null,"time":"2016-02-15T21:00:00+01:00"},"location":"Prenzlauer Berg, Berlin, Germany","description":"Football test","color_id":"9","ical_uid":"od9404scajlnskmsc8t32peljk@google.com"},{"start":{"date":null,"time":"2016-02-17T09:00:00+01:00"},"end":{"date":null,"time":"2016-02-17T10:00:00+01:00"},"location":"Neuk\u00f6lln, Berlin, Germany","description":"Baseball Test","color_id":"7","ical_uid":"jtek50q1pche91gl5q1i1pk028@google.com"},{"start":{"date":null,"time":"2016-02-18T10:00:00+01:00"},"end":{"date":null,"time":"2016-02-18T11:00:00+01:00"},"location":"Baseball Test","description":"Baseball Test","color_id":"2","ical_uid":"71l2cak9b7jvp1fmpuc68fshg8@google.com"},{"start":{"date":null,"time":"2016-02-16T20:00:00+01:00"},"end":{"date":null,"time":"2016-02-16T21:00:00+01:00"},"location":"Somewhere","description":"Elsewhere","color_id":"2","ical_uid":"d6d20ep8tvlo594eeinhv02170@google.com"},{"start":{"date":null,"time":"2016-02-13T08:00:00+01:00"},"end":{"date":null,"time":"2016-02-13T09:00:00+01:00"},"location":"Prenzlauer Berg, Berlin, Germany","description":"YEAH! Football!","color_id":"1","ical_uid":"qm3vrnd73eqnls2lsurm9hmc3s@google.com"},{"start":{"date":null,"time":"2016-02-15T09:00:00+01:00"},"end":{"date":null,"time":"2016-02-15T10:00:00+01:00"},"location":"Neuk\u00f6lln, Berlin, Germany","description":"test name","color_id":"2","ical_uid":"7t4l93vnkfedhaeuk3vkaqmssg@google.com"}]}];
    var converted = [];
    $.each(obj[0].events,function(i,eItem){
     formatted = moment(eItem.start.time);

                converted.push({

                    date: formatted.format('YYYY-MM-DD'),

                    formatted_date: formatted.format('DD.MM.YY'),
                    formatted_time: formatted.format('HH:mm') + ' Uhr',

                    location: eItem.location,
                    description: eItem.description,
                    link: eItem.ical_uid,
                    category: eItem.color_id == null ? 'default' : eItem.color_id

                });

    });
 console.log(converted);
```

jsfiddle:https://jsfiddle.net/o1f62n4g/1/

Comment: I have tried this, and the attributes appear in a list in the console.

However, when I substitute the 'var obj' for the live file, the data disappears.